# Degree of minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

While working through my book I've run into a question where I'm not too sure what is being asked of me/how to start thinking about it. It states:

> Suppose $E$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and $d \in E -\mathbb{Z}_7$. Find $\deg(d/\mathbb{Z_7})$ if
>
> a) $d^{5}=2$
>
> ...

and then they list a couple more cases for me to figure out. How am I supposed to figure these types of things out? I feel like this is going to be a one trick wonder but I've been looking at it and been at a loss.

Comment: I posted an answer. Did you check it up? Think of accepting (by licking on the gray uparrow to the left of the answer, or if unhelpful click the downarrow). Don't keep questions/answers  in a limbo

Answer (score 0):

Check first if  $2$ is already a $5$th power; for example $4$ is not only a square it is a $5$th power too: $2^5=32\equiv 4\pmod 7$.  And $3^5=243\equiv5\pmod 7$. Their product and inverses are also fifth powers which are $6,2,3$ respectively, and $1$ is always  a power. So every number is a 5th power in this field.